# Can you get HealthKit data from a specific user defined time in SwiftUI?

Tags: date, swiftui, timestamp, healthkit

I'd like to get healthkit data from a specific time.

For example :

A user creates a 'goal' module, the goal is to walk a total of X steps or X km in order to complete it

Is it possible to count the data from the point that this goal module is created by the user?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/reading_data_from_healthkit

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10664

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.